# Asp.net owin UseCookieAuthentication ExpireTimeSpan

Tags: asp.net, cookies, owin

I have a Asp.net mvc project that utilizes cookie authentication with auth 0. I have set the following configuration where `ExpireTimeSpan` is set to 10s.

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),

                // Configure SameSite as needed for your app. Lax works well for most scenarios here but
                // you may want to set SameSiteMode.None for HTTPS
                CookieSameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax,
                // More information on why the CookieManager needs to be set can be found here: 
                // https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/wiki/System.Web-response-cookie-integration-issues
                CookieManager = new SameSiteCookieManager(new SystemWebCookieManager()),
                ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)
            });
```

Looking at the browser, I see the cookie has an expiration of "Session".

[image]

My understanding is that this means that the cookie will last until the user closes the browser; however, the ExpireTimeSpan refers to the AuthTicket inside the cookie, and that should expire in 10s.

After about a minute, when I try to make another call to a place that requires authentication, it still allowed me to reach the page, but shouldn't it reject the expired ticket and force me to log back in?

I also saw the cookie value is still `xwMhubv....`, so I know it's not generating a new cookie value in the background.

Am I misunderstanding something, or am I missing another configuration somewhere?

Thanks.